# Excel VBA copy range from one sheet and paste it one cell at a time in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a range of data from one sheet and paste it, one cell at a time, in another sheet.

Let's say Sheet1 has the data in range A1 to C5. A1 till last row needs to be copied and pasted in Sheet2 **but one cell at a time** starting from first not empty cell in column A till last copied data. Is this possible?

The reason why this has to be done one cell at a time is because for every updated cell a small .txt file with the new value for this cell will be created. This file is then used to sync data across multiple excel files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yep, that is possible with a loop.

Comment: Hi BigBen, Is it possible for you to give a simple example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use the copy/paste functionality because it is much slower than directly assigning a cell's value to another cell.

Try something like this:

```
Dim sourceWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim destinationWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rangeToTransfer As Range

Set sourceWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets("<name of source worksheet>")
Set destinationWorksheet = myWorkbook.Worksheets("<name of destination worksheet>")
Set rangeToTransfer = sourceWorksheet.Range("A1:C5")

Dim lastUsedRow As Integer
Dim rowIndex As Integer
Dim columnIndex As Integer

lastUsedRow = destinationWorksheet.Cells(destinationWorksheet.Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).row

For rowIndex = 1 To rangeToTransfer.Rows.Count
   For columnIndex = 1 To rangeToTransfer.Columns.Count
      destinationWorksheet.Cells(lastUsedRow + rowIndex, columnIndex).Value2 = rangeToTransfer.Cells(rowIndex, columnIndex).Value2      
   Next   
Next
```

I am making an assumption here:

- You know the exact range you are trying to copy - A1:C5

But I hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I tried your code with some adjustments and it works untill the pasting part.

- The first assumption can be correct, the range to copy can be a fixed range.

- Second assumption is incorrect. The range to paste/copy it to is dynamic. This always has to start from first empty cell in first assigned column. So if the first empty cell is A5, then start pasting there.

If further clarification is needed please let me know.

Comment: Okay I updated my answer based on your feedback. Let me know if it works as needed.

Comment: Thank you, mattjr747, this helped a lot. I've marked your answer as the solution to my question. This is more than enough for me to keep building on!